# Transforming TypeScript into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wondering how is it possible to transform the [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) into JavaScript in a cross platform manner. I'm aware about availability of [node package manager for typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download), but are there any other alternatives which can be used on the server side?

Comment: What do you mean by "cross-plattform manner"?

Comment: Is there a library or an application which can transform typescript to js on major platforms (Windows, Linux, OSX)?

Comment: your browser is a JS engine so it can compile TS

Comment: That is true, but how can you achieve that on the server-side?

Comment: I would have found it more understandable if you would say that you're looking forward to integrate that into some kind of web resource manager that runs in the java VM. Just an example, would be helpful to ask specifically.

Comment: The question is more generic, because I was curious about all available options.

Comment: Would love to understand the people who downvote the question without explaining it. Pretty lame behavior, considering that the answers were upvoted massively.

Comment: The typescript compiler is written in typescript, and compiles to javascript. That means typescript can be compiled to javascript on any platform that javascript can run on. I suppose people downvote your question because they find this obvious. If you're asking for server-side javascript runtimes, then that's just an easy google query away.

Comment: Not everything can be found on google, especially when it is about a new language or experience people have about a technology. Not asking a question on SO because google exist, is not a valid reason.

Comment: Server-side javascript runtimes are not a new technology.

Comment: Perhaps people downvote your question because you seem to be clinging to a very specific use case.  You wish to use TypeScript but are resistant to using NodeJS - which BTW is, contrary to your assertion, widely used and minimal bother to install.  The Rhino suggestion is rather clever way to satisfy your demands for JVM.

I get the impression that you prefer Java, so perhaps you could explain why you are even considering TypeScript.  They are two very different beasts.

Comment: The reason why I'm considering TypeScript, is because it is a web language similar to coffeeScript which probably will become popular in the future and might be used as an alternative language to javascript.  Being able to use TypeScript in development and transforming it to javascript during the build is a valid use-case which would be nice to achieve. Node.js is a good option, but I was wondering about other alternatives (if any exists).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Short version:** use Node if you can. It's becoming unavoidable nowadays.

Maybe it's not the answer you want, but as everybody mentioned, the compiler is a JS file, so, your options are the options of executing a JS file.

In Windows, there are 2 obvious ones, Node, and Windows Script Host.

You know about node already, the other option is a component that comes with all versions of Windows (I think), you can do it like this:

```
cscript path/to/tsc.js source-file.ts
```

You can see all compiler options by just:

```
cscript path/to/tsc.js
```

<strike>On Linux I assume you should be able to use (in addition to node):</strike>

- V8 standalone shell, replace `node` or `cscript` with `v8-shell`
- ExecJS https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
- Any other JS runner available on the selected platform (another answer mentioned Rhino for example)

**Update:** Another answer suggests the compiler API is only compatible with node and Windows Script Host (cscript tool), so, if correct, then on Linux you'll need Node to compile TypeScript.

If you are looking for something like `apt get tsc` (or whatever the Linux/Mac package managers are like), I think there isn't.

I remember reading somewhere that the I/O is optimized for Node and Windows Script Host, so, if you have problems with options, you'll probably end up with Node if seeking platform independence.

**Update:** Another answer here confirms the same about compatibility.

Comment: Executing `tsc.js` using WSH (cscript) is not supported anymore ([more info](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41311)). According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388889/typescript-2-4-2-compiler-not-working-with-windows-script-host#comment77739404_45388889) the latest version which supports executing via cscript is [v1.8.10](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v1.8.10)

Answer (score 37):

The TypeScript compiler is built in TypeScript, and hence is available as a JS file ([`tsc.js`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/raw/02547fe664a1b5d1f07ea459f054c34e356d3746/lib/tsc.js)) that can be run using just about any ES3-compiliant VM or JS implementation.

That said, the compiler's current file I/O infrastructure only supports Node and Windows Scripting Host file APIs.  If you'd like to recommend for support for another environment, feel free to reach out to the team at our [GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript)   (Formerly [CodePlex](http://typescript.codeplex.com))

Comment: Thanks. Ideally, I would prefer to have a java open source framework which compiles typescript to javascript. Since java is already cross platform, it would be possible to use it on any OS.

Comment: @AlexObjelean, it is already possible to run the TypeScript compiler on any platform, since it compiles to JS.

Comment: Ok, let me put this another way. How would you transform the typescript on the server-side during the build?

Comment: @AlexObjelean: By using the compiler, that is for what a compiler is for. The compiler is in .js.

Comment: `npm install -g typescript` will put `tsc` in your PATH on any platform that Node/NPM supports. This includes Windows, OS X, and Linux. It really isn't that hard folks...

Comment: @AlexObjelean http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html can be used to run an external command, such as the typescript compiler, from a JVM language such as Java. The typescript tag is hardly appropriate for such a question though.

Comment: as others have said, node does fairly well in being cross-platform. What platform is your server running on? Have you checked if it can support node, which is intended to run on the server? If you've got your heart set on running within Java, there's always the Rhino javascript engine in Java. A small amount of hacking on the typescript js to support Rhino IO apis (or even better, write a simple js shim to expose the Rhino apis as the node apis used by tsc).

Answer (score 16):

From the command line you can use ts-node:

```
npm install ts-node
```

Then call the command like this:

```
tsc file.ts --outFile file.js
```

Comment: The second command worked for me but I had to install tsc with `apt install node-typescript` ... on Ubuntu.

Comment: Add the `-g` option on install or try instead `node_modules/.bin/tsc file.ts --outFile file.js` in the directory you installed it in.

Answer (score 12):

Concretely, on the server (assuming your server has Node.js available), you'd simply run:

```
node path/to/tsc.js yourFile1.ts yourFile2.ts [etc]
```

You can run that command without any input filenames to see the command-line help for tsc.js.

Comment: `npm install tsc; npx tsc main.ts` will output `main.js`

Answer (score 7):

I have a project which compiles Typescript to Javascript in Java:

https://github.com/martypitt/typescript4j

As discussed in other answers, this makes use of Rhino, so has no dependencies on `npm` or `node`.

Here's an example:

```
// Instantiate the compiler:
TypescriptCompiler compiler = new TypescriptCompiler();

// Compile a string:
String output = compiler.compile("class Greeter { greeting: string; }");

// Or, compile and output to a file:
compiler.compile(new File("example.ts"), new File('output.js'));
```

I use it in [another project - 'Bakehouse'](https://github.com/martypitt/bakehouse) to perform on-the-fly compilation of typescript resources within Spring environments

Comment: This is something wro4j supports since version 1.6.0: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/AvailableProcessors

Comment: @AlexObjelean The wro4j implementation relies on calling out to `tsc`, which - in turn - relies on `npm` being installed.  This implementation doesn't, as it runs exclusively within Rhino.  This is why on the page you linked to, the TypescriptProcessor mentions "not supported on all platforms"

Comment: that is true. Adding a rhino implementation is on the roadmap. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If it's Java that you need to target then you could run tsc.js with the Rhino engine as part of your build process.

Answer (score 2):

To compile ts -> js: node is available for all common platforms, so I fail to see why you'd want to have a tsc.java when you already have a tsc.js.  Installing node is no big deal.  In fact, it's easier than Java.

Once you have your proj.js file, you can then copy it to which ever deployment platform you wish to use.

From my point of view, JavaScript - or more accurately ECMAScript is an alternative to Java.  So I'm happy that I don't have to wrangle JVM etc to use the tool.  But if you prefer Java, then why even bother with JS?

Comment: I don't see ECMAScript as an alternative to Java. And I would rather prefer to wrangle JVM to achieve a goal, rather than install node (which is great tool but it is not widely adopted yet).

Comment: @AlexObjelean if you're so inclined, it should be possible to get tsc to work under Rhino. You'd have to implement the `IIO` interface found in http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d397c54a55db#src%2fcompiler%2fio.ts

Answer (score 1):

**SublimeText2 Trick**
You can transpile typescript to javascript directly from SublimeText2 (you need node) :

Create a `Typescript.sublime-build` file in `/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User` with this content :

```
{
"cmd": ["tsc", "$file"],
"selector" : "source.ts",
"path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
}
```

then, now, you can transpile your code with ctrl+B or cmd+B

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with this, and can compile TypeScript with javascript with the following code:

```
<script src=typescript.js></script>

<script>

var scriptText = ""
        + "/// <reference path=\"test.ts\"/>" + "\r\n"
        + "class Car {"
        + "     constructor (private name: string) { } "
        + "     getName() { "
        + "         var juice = new Juice();"
        + "         return name; "
        + "     } "
        + "} "
        + "var car = new Car('Subaru Impreza');"
        + "console.log(car.getName());";





var TextWriter = function () { };

TextWriter.prototype = {
collected: '',

Write: function (sc) {
    this.collected += sc;
},
WriteLine: function(sc) {
    this.collected += sc + '\n';
},
toString: function() {
    return this.collected;
}
};

var output = new TextWriter();
var tsc = new TypeScript.TypeScriptCompiler(output);

var script = tsc.addUnit(scriptText, "");

tsc.emit();

console.log(output.toString());

</script>
```

It's not exactly ideal though. I'm trying to get something running so I can convert TypeScript to JS within C# (using Javascript .NET), but i'm getting a stack overflow on the ts.addUnit call.

Comment: There is a client-side script which does this: [TypeScript Compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile)

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

First, installed the `typescript` *node module* >> `npm install -g typescript`.  This gives a command line utility `tsc`.

Next, `tsc gulpfile.ts gulp-config.ts typings/tsd.d.ts`

- this will `transpile` the `gulpfile.ts` and `gulp-config.ts` files to `gulpfile.js` and `gulp-config.js`.  We supply the `typings/tsd.d.ts` file as reference for correct transpilation.
- The `typescript` *node module* covers many options >> `tsc -h` to specify *output directory or file, etc.*.

Comment: File 'typings/tsd.d.ts' not found.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't wanna use `ts-node`, because it is slow, instead follow following steps  for fast `.ts` files compilation (Make sure node is installed):

1. `npm i -D @types/node typescript nodemon`
2. `npx tsconfig.json` and select `node` from the list. You are free to modify it as per your needs.
3. Create a file names `src/index.ts` in your project root.
4. Then in your `package.json`, add the following 2 scripts:

   `"scripts":  { "watch":  "tsc -w", "dev":  "nodemon dist/index.js" },`
5. Then use:

   `npm run watch`

   `npm run dev`

And, it will automatically look for changes in `.ts` files and you can see the compiled file output in the terminal as you go!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "firebase -tool" you can use

```
npm run build
```

inside your functions directory.