# TypeScript 2.4.2 compiler not working with Windows Script Host

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile a sample script using the lib/tsc.js file in the 2.4.2 release of TypeScript.

At the Windows console I'm typing:

```
cscript lib\tsc.js test.ts
```

It gives the following error:

```
lib\tsc.js(216, 31) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected identifier
```

I had tried with the newest version of TypeScript on GitHub but it gave a similar error.

The sample script is:

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

WScript.Echo(greeter("World"));
```

I'm pretty sure this used to work for an earlier version of TypeScript. Am I missing something?

Please assume I can't install Node or anything else.

Comment: WSH's JScript has been frozen since Windows XP was released, so I t does not support ECMAScript 5 features that TypeScript now depends on. You will have to restrict yourself to an older version of the JScript-based TSC that supports ES3.

Comment: @Dai Ah - thank you! For future readers - it looks like it needs to be the last version of the 1.* series, [1.8.10](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v1.8.10).