# Is possible to use typescript in client side?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

recently I started with TypeScript and I do not like to use node or ts compiler
I want to know if there are a TypeScript transpiler that allow me to use typescript in browser like babel standalon that allow me to use ES6 in browser
for example I want to write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tscomplier.js"></script>
 <script type="text/typescript" src="typescript_fille.ts"></script>
```

another question is what is typescript.js on cdn
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/2.6.2/typescript.js

and what is babel core on browser 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js

Thanks :)

Comment: I want to use typescript in browser for example     <script type="text/typescript" src="file.ts"></script>

Comment: Ok but what is this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/2.6.2/typescript.js and what is this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transforming TypeScript into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Of course. But you need to transpile it to JS, which is the main purpose of TS.

Comment: I want transpire run on client side like babel standalone see my comment above