# I'm trying to translate an example of TypeScript into JavaScript, and I'm not sure how to convert it

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript, nativescript

I'm working with an example of NativeScript which uses TypeScript to process the logic. My working project uses JavaScript and I want to bring the example into my project.

I tried to bring the code into the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

```
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { Page, View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { SwipeActionsEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";

import { HomeViewModel } from "./home-view-model";

export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    const page = <Page>args.object;

    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}

export function onSwipeCellStarted(args: SwipeActionsEventData) {
    const swipeLimits = args.data.swipeLimits;
    swipeLimits.left = 360;
    swipeLimits.right = 0;
    swipeLimits.threshold = 200;
}

I'm just wanting to know how it would be formated using JS
```

Comment: see [transforming ts to js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQG4FMB2MAiBDGPOAXzgDMoIQ4AiGTAZwFoBjadJkCAEwFcAbdAwD03AnmEQARg3RRUeKYJoBuAFChIsRHAAKeAOboANHABqwdAHcS5StTqNW7TjwFDhvYMLCH0qjXBoeCQAZStgMHQAQRYYYAhGNCxccVsKKlpMAmAMBhYoSJgmLyZ+YAYYVEsrAMCtELgACSp0C2sAWR50fnT7WgA6YQALVqZq61duHrr0AA8G8l5MOITMOGzqgxzMAwAVCAAKPCgDBgAuFAxsfEIASkQ1OGe4NkZ4XyM4AF44AB59EYAHwnM4DaQAK3QcXUTxen3QAykwEw3BRBgAwokYPN4L9MNZmq12lYutN+Ic7upiGo1PNFmRlqtEnBEuFIugMT1+KFCLB0NxjqcLnB2VFYvFEgxkjdxA8EHDnm9KnAGBEogAZUDAGAMH5wUEMAZiQgDNUcrUgHUMdQvVXq9CW60DQRkPFwADMADYAAy2l7mzXa3UDQoGYbuv2K+0W4NGmDDKBCUb8bj6gBMPqjxCAA

Comment: Just remove the typings syntax from the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HomeViewModel } from "./home-view-model";
export function navigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}
export function onSwipeCellStarted(args) {
    const swipeLimits = args.data.swipeLimits;
    swipeLimits.left = 360;
    swipeLimits.right = 0;
    swipeLimits.threshold = 200;
}
```

Or if the application doesn't support 'import' syntax

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model").HomeViewModel;
export function navigatingTo(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}
export function onSwipeCellStarted(args) {
    const swipeLimits = args.data.swipeLimits;
    swipeLimits.left = 360;
    swipeLimits.right = 0;
    swipeLimits.threshold = 200;
}
```