# How to translate a tsx file to a js file for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a React Project and have a bunch of tsx files that I want to convert as use as javascript for my project. How should I do that?

Comment: This question has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript
Check https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ for a quick compile fix

Comment: I went through that question but its not working with tsx files that are special to react. So I think the question is a little different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am working on a React Project and have a bunch of tsx files that I want to convert as use as javascript for my project. How should I do that

You can use the typescript compiler e.g.

```
npx -p typescript tsc somefile.tsx
```

Comment: One can also use tsConfig file so this will be done automatically on file save.

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, while the web is full of guide on how to translate React Javascript into Typescript, I don't found any reverse guide (so strange...).
Anyway, I had same problem some time ago and I found useful get one of those guide JS => TS for React and read backwards. For example, I used [this](https://medium.com/swlh/convert-your-javascript-react-app-to-typescript-the-easy-guide-631592dc1876) guide. When he said "JavaScript looks like that so you can translate this into Typescript in this way..." I did the contrary (and it worked!). Of course you can skip all the dependencies part.
Try and let us know.

Comment: In short: reverse engineering. Thanks for the hint plus one