# How can I include a typescript file in dist using Vue CLI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm trying to make a chrome extension with Vue 3 using Vue CLI which requires a script to run in the background.

I have a `background.ts` file in my `src/` directory, and want to know how I can configure Vue CLI to compile that and put it in the `dist/` folder when I build the project.

Comment: Typescript files would need to be converted to a `js` file. You can probably do with a typescript cli command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript

Comment: @Riza Khan I was considering just compiling that one script and copying it into `dist/`  in a npm script after I built the project, but it seems kinda janky and there are probably better ways (that I don't know of, hence why I asked) though webpack config or Vue CLI config.  That might just be what I need to do for now until I find out a better way.

Comment: You didn't explain why you need that. This sounds like XY problem.