# Is there a problem mixing javascript and typescript in node projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am very new to node.js and typescript. I am trying to learn by porting an existing application over from python. I am getting a syntax error in a place I do not expect.

I have a class that is the workhorse of the project. It is in a file called `myClass.ts`

```
myProject
└── js
    ├── commands
    │   └── rules.js
    ├── myClass.ts
    └── main.js
```

`rules.js` includes `myClass` as:

```
try {
    const {myClass} = require("../myClass.ts")
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

I am using PyCharm and can put a breakpoint in the catch block.  The error points to the constructor in the class.  The error is:

```
/home/me/PycharmProjects/myProject/js/myClass.ts:44
        rule_type: string,
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/PycharmProjects/myProject/js/commands/rules.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

`myClass` is too big to fit in here.  It starts:

```
const {randomInt} = require('crypto')

class myClass {
    constructor(
        rule_type: string,
        display_type: string,
        range_min: number     = 1,
        range_max: number     = 10000,
        display_mapping: {}   = undefined,
        value_adjustments: {} = undefined,
    ) {
        this.rule_type = die_type
        this.display_type = display_type
        this.range_min = Math.trunc(range_min)
        this.range_max = Math.trunc(range_max)
        this.display_mapping = display_mapping
        this.value_adjustments = value_adjustments
    }

    ...//a bunch of methods, etc
}

exports.myClass = myClass;
```

If I take the `: string` type hint away, then the error just falls down to the next type hint. Is there a problem mixing javascript and typescript in this way?

Why am I mixing js and ts? I found a sample node project that seems to be a reasonable starting point for what I want to do.  I figured that trying out typescript for this class might be a good exercise.

** Edit **

Thanks to all.  Much to learn...

Comment: What I can see is, your error is coming from node.js. But node.js of course understand only Javascript and TypeScript has to be transpiled before.

Comment: do you have enabled `"allowJs": true` inside your `tsconfig`?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript. That means that Typescript understands javascript just fine, but Javascript will think Typescript code is full of syntax errors. A project needs to be configured to use typescript so that typescript code is compiled to Javascript before it's run in node or the browser.

Comment: Look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest mixing `.ts` files and `.js` files in the same project while starting out. Since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, changing every `.js` file to end with `.ts` should not break anything. Then you can use  `tsc` to compile everything to native JavaScript.

Make sure to enable `allowJs` in your `tsconfig` file.