# convert a typescript fuction to in js

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

```
function checkboxFormatter(
  { onChange, ...props }: CheckboxFormatterProps,
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>
) {
  function handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    onChange(e.target.checked, (e.nativeEvent as MouseEvent).shiftKey);
  }

  return <input type="checkbox" ref={ref} {...props} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

any buddy convert this is JavaScript code

i need hear to use him in js in react

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using tsc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678716/transforming-typescript-into-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

```
function checkboxFormatter(props, ref) {
  function handleChange(e) {
    props.onChange(e.target.checked, (e.nativeEvent as MouseEvent).shiftKey);
  }

  return <input type="checkbox" ref={ref} {...props} onChange={handleChange}/>;
}
```